# Child entities fetches with lazy fetching

Tags: java, hibernate

I've an issue while fetching data with Hibernate Spring. I'm trying to figure out why a specific Get request does not work as I expected.

[Database lay out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKRW3.png)

The goal is to get a list of all countries in the table country with the following method:

```
> @GetMapping("/getCountry") public List <Country> getCountry(){ 
>   return(List<Country>) countryRepo.findAll();  }
```

The country entity is:

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="country", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<PortOfLoading> portOfLoadings;

    public Country() {

    } 
//getters and setters omitted
```

The Port of Loading entity is:

```
@Entity
```

public class PortOfLoading {

```
@Id
private int id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference
private Country country;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "port_of_loading_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<Container> containers;

public PortOfLoading() {

} //getters and setters are omitted
```

I would expect hibernate to make a query like this:

```
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_4_, country0_.name as name2_4_ from country country0_
```

But instead of that, hibernate starts to fetch all port of loadings for that entity and after that also all the containers for each port of loading:

```
Hibernate: select portofload0_.country_id as country_3_5_0_, portofload0_.id as id1_5_0_, portofload0_.id as id1_5_1_, portofload0_.country_id as country_3_5_1_, portofload0_.name as name2_5_1_ from port_of_loading portofload0_ where portofload0_.country_id=?

Hibernate: select containers0_.port_of_loading_id as port_of_8_2_0_, containers0_.id as id1_2_0_, containers0_.id as id1_2_1_, containers0_.carrier_id as carrier_5_2_1_, containers0_.container_reference as containe2_2_1_, containers0_.container_sort_id as containe6_2_1_, containers0_.port_of_loading_country_id as port_of_7_2_1_, containers0_.ocean_freight_costs_invoiced as ocean_fr3_2_1_, containers0_.port_of_loading_id as port_of_8_2_1_, containers0_.terminal_handeling_costs_invoiced as terminal4_2_1_ from container containers0_ where containers0_.port_of_loading_id=?
```

Because of all the other queries, it takes a very long time to get the data and I've been struggling to figure out why it is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share code of the `findAll()` method?

Comment: The findAll() method is a Standard method of the crudRepository.

Comment: Can you try @JoinColumn(name = "country_id") in PortOfLoading class

Comment: Since you are directly returning the entity and not using any POJO. The additional queries might not be called when you execute the `findAll()`. It might be called by the `controller` when returning the result. Split the `findAll()` and `return` statements and check when additional queries are executed

Comment: Try including jackson annotation JsonIgnore on top of private List<PortOfLoading> portOfLoadings;  annotation JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference which gets serialized normally.  This may be the reason why child queries gets executed.

Comment: If I split the findAll() and return statement and manually print the Countries it works perfectly, but after that with the return statement the other queries are called. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The function FindAll() fetches all the data with the right querie. But the return statement on the getCountry() method fetches all the other entities. Adding @JsonIgnore solved the problem with the return statement:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="country", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private List<PortOfLoading> portOfLoadings;
```